# Bibliography numbered by chapter e.g. 1.1 A. Author

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I'm writing a thesis with the references appearing in each chapter required to be numbered by the chapter. e.g. `[1.1]` for the first reference in chapter 1; `[3.2]` for the second reference in chapter 3. I'm inputing manually using `thebibliography` environment (i.e. not BibTeX, don't judge me!) but each chapter presents references as `[1]`, `[2]` etc.

To summarize, I want the references as `[1.1]`, `[1.2]` etc. rather than `[1]`, `[2]` - how can I achieve this? I can amend the citations as such using `\renewcommand\citeform{\thechapter.}` - but this does not change the bibliography accordingly.

Each chapter is written independently and input into the main document using `\input{Chapter}`, and is formatted as follows:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{cite}
\renewcommand\citeform{\thechapter.}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

This is the case \cite{Ref_1a, Ref_1b}.

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{Ref_1a}
A. Author, "ref 1.1," Journal, X(Y), pp (YYYY)

\bibitem{Ref_1b}
B. Author, "ref 1.2," Journal, X(Y), pp (YYYY)

\end{thebibliography}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

This is still the case \cite{Ref_2a, Ref_2b}.


\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{Ref_2a}
A. Author, "ref 2.1," Journal, X(Y), pp (YYYY)

\bibitem{Ref_2b}
B. Author, "ref 2.2," Journal, X(Y), pp (YYYY)

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  First, what is your actual question here?  Is something not working?  Second, please consider including a minimal working example in your question; it greatly reduces the amount of work required to help you.

Comment: Thanks! Basically I just want the references as [1.1], [1.2] etc. rather than [1], [2] - so it's not that something isn't working per se, just I don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay what I was looking for for an understanding of how to control the `cite` package. Still new to LaTeX so this was a learning process. Seems I simply needed to renew the `citeform` and `biblabel` commands as follows:

```
\usepackage{cite}
\renewcommand\citeform{\thechapter.}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\thechapter.#1.}
```